# Restricción UNIQUE

Tags: mysql

como puedo colocar una restricción UNIQUE a un campo de tipo LONGBLOB de una base de datos en MYSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es algo contradictorio querer poner una restricción `UNIQUE` a ese tipo de campo. Primeramente no veo qué utilidad tendría y segundo, los índices tienen tamaños limitados, mientras que el tamaño de estos campos es ilimitado.

Si de todos modos quieres hacerlo, es posible, pero debes saber que no todo el campo puede ser parte del índice, sino solamente una parte de él, o sea un prefijo, algo así como los `N` primeros caracteres.

Está explicado en el [Manual de referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-indexes.html):

> Cuando indexa una columna `BLOB`<sup>1</sup> o `TEXTO`, debe
>   especificar una longitud de prefijo para el índice. Por ejemplo:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (blob_col BLOB, INDEX(blob_col(10)));
> ```

En este caso el índice serían solamente los primeros diez bytes del campo.

El tamaño límite, como explica el Manual es medido en bytes y varía según el engine de las tablas y otras configuraciones:

> Los prefijos pueden tener una longitud de hasta 767 bytes para las
>   tablas de `InnoDB` que usan el formato de fila `REDUNDANT` o
>   `COMPACT`. El límite de longitud del prefijo es de 3072 bytes para las
>   tablas `InnoDB` que utilizan el formato de fila `DYNAMIC` o
>   `COMPRESSED`. Para las tablas `MyISAM`, el límite de longitud del
>   prefijo es de 1000 bytes.
>
> **Nota:**
>
> Los límites de los prefijos se miden en bytes, mientras que la
>   longitud del prefijo en las sentencias `CREATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE` y
>   `CREATE INDEX` se interpreta como el número de caracteres para los tipos
>   de cadenas no binarias (`CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `TEXT`) y el número de bytes para
>   los tipos de cadenas binarias (`BINARY`, `VARBINARY`, `BLOB`). Tenga esto
>   en cuenta al especificar una longitud de prefijo para una columna de
>   cadena no binaria que utiliza un conjunto de caracteres multibyte.

---

1. Aquí está comprendido también `LONGBLOB`

Comment: Lo que pasa es que tengo una tabla llamada image, con campos id(int) e image(longblod). Como puedo hacer para que las imagenes que inserte en el campo image no se me repitan y sean únicas?

Comment: @DFMDANIEL Como ya explica la respuesta, dado que `LONGBLOB` puede tener un tamaño infinito jamás podrás meter todo el valor en un índice, además de lo costoso que eso podría ser. Sólo puedes poner una parte del contenido como índice. Lo mejor sería crear una estrategia, como asignarle un nombre único a la imagen. Al momento de crearla le das un nombre y declaras esa columna (`VARCHAR`)  como `UNIQUE`. Tal y como ocurre en las carpetas normales, donde un mismo archivo no puede tener más de un nombre. Esa unicidad se basa en el nombre del archivo, no en su contenido, lo cual sería inviable.